# Django .po translation

Tags: poedit

I have used the following .po file in Poedit to use it in a django app (locale\el\LC_MESSAGES\django.po) for greek characters in templates.

> ## SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
>
> ## Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
>
> ## This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
>
> ## FIRST AUTHOR , YEAR.
>
> ## msgid "" msgstr "" "Project-Id-Version: Apografi\n" "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n" "POT-Creation-Date: 2016-05-04
>
> 11:27+0300\n" "PO-Revision-Date: 2016-05-09 09:51+0200\n"
>   "Last-Translator: Kostas \n" "Language-Team: LANGUAGE
>   \n" "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" "Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=UTF-8\n" "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n" "Plural-Forms:
>   nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n" "X-Generator: Poedit 1.6.4\n"
>   "X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n" "Language: el_GR\n"
>
> ## : .\templates\widgets\tables\tables.html:69 msgid "%(count)s of %(total)s" msgstr "%(count)s από %(total)s"
>
> ## : .\templates\category\create.html:16 .\templates\authority\create.html:16
>
> ## : .\templates\division\create.html:16 msgid "Create" msgstr "Δημιουργία"
>
> ## : .\templates\category\update.html:17 .\templates\authority\update.html:17
>
> ## : .\templates\division\update.html:16 msgid "Update" msgstr "Ενημέρωση"
>
> ## : .\templates\category\delete.html:15 .\templates\authority\delete.html:15
>
> ## : .\templates\division\delete.html:15 msgid "Delete" msgstr "Διαγραφή"
>
> ## : .\templates\category\delete.html:18 .\templates\authority\delete.html:18
>
> ## : .\templates\division\delete.html:18 msgid "Are you sure you want to delete the selected" msgstr "Θέλετε να διαγράψετε την επιλεγνένη
>
> εγγραφή"
>
> ## : .\templates\widgets\form.html:18 msgid "Save" msgstr "Αποθήκευση"
>
> ## : .\templates\authority\detail.html:34 .\templates\division\detail.html:34
>
> ## : .\templates\category\detail.html:34 msgid "pedio" msgstr "Όνομα Πεδίου"
>
> ## : .\templates\authority\detail.html:35 .\templates\division\detail.html:35
>
> ## : .\templates\category\detail.html:35 msgid "timh" msgstr "Τιμή Πεδίου"
>
> ## : .\templates\division\list.html:15 .\templates\authority\list.html:15
>
> ## : .\templates\category\list.html:15 msgid "Add" msgstr "Προσθήκη"
>
> ## : .\templates\division\list.html:25 .\templates\authority\list.html:25
>
> ## : .\templates\category\list.html:25 msgid "Search" msgstr "Αναζήτηση"
>
> msgid "apografi" msgstr "Απογραφή"
>
> msgid "category" msgstr "Κατηγορία"
>
> msgid "authority" msgstr "Διεύθυνση"
>
> msgid "division" msgstr "Τμήμα"

Using the validation of Poedit showed me No erros that validation is OK and translation file should be used. 
[image: Poedit validation result]
This .po file works for 90% OK for me but when i try to use trans inside these bootstrap tags i do not get translated result but the source:

1.

> table class="table table-bordered">
>           thead
>              tr
>                   th{% trans "pedio" %}/th
>                   th{{ _("timh") }}/th
>               /tr
>           /thead

2.

> a class="btn btn-primary pull-right">  {{ _("Update") }} /a 
>    a class="btn btn-primary
>   pull-right">  {{ _("Delete")
>   }} /a

Answer (score 0):

Where are these bootstrap tags ? You shouldn't mix template tags (ie `{% trans "text" %}`) with functions (ie `_("text")`). The trans and blocktrans template tags should be used in your templates, the `ugettext` (aliased as `_`) to your python code.

So, for example instead of `{{ _("Update") }}` you should use `{% trans "Update" %}`.

Comment: Same thing for me as:                                                                                           <div class='container'>
    <h3> </h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans "pedio" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "timh" %}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>                                                                                                 <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> {% trans "Update" %}</a>

Comment: I have got three folders in my templates folder: templates/categories/*.html, templates/authority/*.html, templates/division/*.html. In categories folder all translation lines work fine, in the other two some translation lines do not work at all. I have compiled them into .mo and they behave as static, i do not know why?